# How to set the same background image for all tabs? (React Native)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, react-native, background

I would like to use the same background image for all my tabs without having to copy paste the code on each of my tabs.

How to have a single code that manages the background image of all my tabs?

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Image, ImageBackground, Button } from 'react-native';

export default class Youtube extends Component {
  render() {
    return (

      <ImageBackground source={require("../assets/images/ici.jpg")} style={{width: '100%', height: '100%'}}>
          <Text style={{color: 'white', fontSize: 40}}>
          Hello{"\n"} 
          </Text>
      </ImageBackground> 
    );}}
```

Comment: Hi, do you want that the Backgroundviews render childs dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is to use the High order component pattern. You can find more information about that pattern [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html)

The basic idea is that you have function that return a component, this function takes parameters and let you compose your component.

You can put the duplicate code here, just call the function with the component of your choice. It will return the newly created component that have the background image for your tab.

You can write something like that:

```
function withBackground(WrappedComponent) {
  return class extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <ImageBackground
          source={require("../assets/images/picture.jpg")}
          style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }}
        >
          <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />
        </ImageBackground>
      );
    }
  };
}
```

And you can use it like that:

```
const YoutubeWithBackground = withBackground(Youtube);
```

Comment: Yes I'm french we can switch in French if you want

Comment: Copy and past the function

Comment: And now create your component like that const YoutubeWithBackground = withBackground(Youtube);

Answer (score 0):

You should use this code

```
 import * as React from 'react';
    import { 
      Text,
      View, 
      Image,
      StyleSheet,  
      ImageBackground, 
      Dimensions
    } from 'react-native';

    const WrapperView = (childs) =>{
      return (
          <ImageBackground source={require("../assets/images/ici.jpg")} style={{width: '100%', height: '100%'}}>
            <Text style={{color: 'white', fontSize: 40}}>
              Hello{"\n"} 
              {childs && childs}
            </Text>
          </ImageBackground> 
        )
    }

    const {
      width: MAX_WIDTH,
      height: MAX_HEIGHT,
    } = Dimensions.get('window');

    export default class Youtube extends React.Component {

      constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state={
          bcksNumber: 10, // change this for your number of bckgrounds
        }
      }

      callOneBackGround = () => {
        return (
          <WrapperView>
          </WrapperView>
        )
      }

      renderMultipleBackgrounds = () =>{ 
        const { bckNumber } = this.state
        for(var i = 0; i < bckNumber, i++ ){
          this.callOneBackGround()
        }
      } 

      render() {
        const { childsNumber } = this.state
        return (
          <View style={styles.mainView}>
          {this.renderMultipleBackgrounds(childsNumber)}
          </View>             
        );
      }
    }

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      mainView:{
        width: MAX_WIDTH,
        height: MAX_HEIGHT,
      }
    });
```